# How to get APNS device token in flutter app without using Firebase?

Tags: flutter, apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns, flutter-notification

I am trying to make a flutter app that uses APNS for iOS push notifications and I do not want to use firebase, as I am using AWS SNS in the backend to deliver the push notifications via APNS. I have the application Identifier set up and Keys generated from the apple developer portal. How can I get the APNS device token, I am stuck at this point, tried multiple things but none worked? Below is my AppDelegate.swfit code

```
    import UIKit
    import Flutter

    @UIApplicationMain
    @objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
      override func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
      ) -> Bool {


        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
      }

      func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) 
      {
        let hexString = map { deviceToken(format: "%02.2hhx", $0)}.joined()
        print(hexString)
        
                      
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

with the AWS Amplify libraries for Flutter you can easy receive a device token.

```
void myTokenReceivedHandler(String token) {
  // Do something with the received token
}

final subscription = Amplify.Notifications.Push.onTokenReceived
  .listen(myTokenReceivedHandler);

// Remember to cancel the subscription when it is no longer needed
subscription.cancel();
```

[here detailed description](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/push-notifications/receive-device-token/q/platform/flutter/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but can I just retrieve the device token without using AWS amplify?